# Visual Studio All c++ functions are not members of global namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I recently installed Visual studio as I'm working to pick up c++ more. However in c++, even running something as simple as a hello world code yields me a huge number of errors such as

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(24,18): error C2039: 'fabs': is not a member of 'global namespace'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(24,22): error C3861: 'fabs': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(28,18): error C2039: 'fabsf': is not a member of 'global namespace'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(28,23): error C3861: 'fabsf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(32,18): error C2039: 'fabsl': is not a member of 'global namespace'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cstdlib(32,23): error C3861: 'fabsl': identifier not found
```

The error seems to be either an issue with my VS setup or my C++ Distribution. Is this a common issue? Has anyone else seen this before?

Here is the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling this code?  Did you create a console project from the project template?  Try creating a simple c++ console project using VS project template and see if you can compile and build with that.

Comment: _"Is this a common issue?"_ If it is, you'll be able to Google it: You can: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/35b8bce8-27c0-4cbb-927c-110118665209/strange-error-with-visual-studio?forum=vcgeneral.

Comment: @noobius This came straight from the Visual Studio template. This is the default code from when you select "C++ Console project"

Comment: Does your project have an "External Dependencies" under the project tree in the solution explorer?

Comment: If you have tried creating another Win32 Console Application "Hello World" , and still you are getting error. I suggest you could try to reinstall your Visual Studio once again.

Comment: @noobius Yes it does.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I've tried reinstalling a few times and looking for any form of configuration and it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Whether you download the visual studio from [the official Microsoft platform](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)?And I suggest you could also check the order of `#include` directives.In the `#include` section the standard header files should always precede the class files written by programmer.